# Unable to use .draggable() function on append div

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to create a guest seating assignment. So users have to drag the names of the users and place them in the table they want them to be in. In the previous section users have added the guest list and categorized them into 4 categories. I am retrieving values from the database based on a categories selected. This is attained through ajax and appending the value in the div.

This is the jquery/ajax part that retrieves the users chooses category and appends the list of names in the category. For example, When they choose family, all the guest names that is under family will be appended.

```
$(data).appendTo('#name-box').hide().fadeIn();
```

This is the PHP part that echos the div to append:

```
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "registration");  
 $val = $_POST["val"];  
 $sql = "SELECT fname FROM guestlist WHERE grouping='".$val."' ";  
 $result=mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die(error());  
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

 echo"<div id=\"name-box-individual\" >&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp".$row['fname']."
      </div>";  }
?>
```

Right now I am trying to drag this div #name-box-individual. But I cant drag the appened div boxes. However, I can drag if the div is from the html.

```
function(){
    $("#name-box-individual").draggable();
}
```

I believe the issue is with the jquery not being able to capture the appended div. Are there solutions to this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can try it using class instead of id, as `<div class=\"name-box-individual\" > ` and js as `$(".name-box-individual").draggable();`

Comment: Are you appending this `<div>` dynamically and not on page load?

Comment: @AswinRamesh Thank you it works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @RahulGupta Thank you. I got it working now.